# Identity theorem for $f(z)=f(z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\} \rightarrow :\mathbb{C}$, I've got to show 
that if  $f(z)=f(z^2)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ then $f(z)$ is constant.

I've got to use the identity theorem here.
I guess that $1$ would be an accumulation point as $f(1)=f(1^2)$. I've defined the series $z_n=1$ with the obvious convergence to $1$. But somehow I fail to show with the identity theorem that $f(0)=f(1)=f(1^2)=f(z)=..$ follows which would imply that $f$ is constant. What am I missing?

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be continuous or holomorphic? Otherwise the statement is false: we may define $f$ as zero anywhere, except on the unit circle, where we may define $f(e^{\pi i t})$ in terms of the binary representation of $t$.

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic. I've edited it.

Comment: There also is an immediate solution using the Laurent series expansion of $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1$ is not an accumulation point of the (constant) sequence $z_n = 1$, so that does not work. What you need is a sequence $(z_n)$ with a limit point $z^\star$ in the domain such that $z_n \ne z^\star$ and $f(z_n) = f(z^\star)$.

A possible choice is the sequence $z_n = 2^{1/2^n} = 2, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}, \ldots$. Then
$$
 z_{n+1}^2 = z_n \implies f(z_{n+1}) = f(z_n) 
$$
and $z_n \to 1$, so that $f(z_n) = f(1)$ for all $n$. Now you can apply the identity theorem.

---

Here is another solution, without the identity theorem. It shows that it is sufficient to require that $f$ is *continuous:*

Fix $a \in \Bbb C \setminus \{0 \}$ and define a sequence $(z_n)$ as
$$
 z_0 = a \, , \, z_{n+1} = \sqrt{z_n}
$$
where the square root is chosen such that $-\pi/2 \le \arg(z_{n+1}) < \pi/2$. Again $f(z_{n+1}) = f(z_n)$ and $z_n \to 1$, so that $f(z_n) = f(1)$ for all $n$.

It  follows that $f(a) = f(1)$. Since $a$ was arbitrary, $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 11):

Let $g(z)=f(\exp(z))$, so g is entire function and $g(z)=g(2z)$. Now it is easy to show that g is bounded since $g(2^kz)=g(z)$. So g is constant function since it is bounded entire function. So f is constant function too.

Comment: $exp(z)$ is entire and has image in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Why is $g$ bounded?

Comment: Because $\sup_{z\in \partial B(0,r)} |g(z)|=\sup_{z\in \partial B(0,r/2)} |g(z)|$ by the above, so $\sup_{z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}}|g(z)|=\sup_{z\in B(0,2)\setminus B(0,1)} |g(z)|<\infty$ by continuity.

Answer (score 4):

Another, different solution, which uses the identity theorem (although, the exponential solution is, of course, very lovely):

Note that $f$ is analytic around $1$, so
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n=f(1+z)=f((1+z)^2)=f(1+z^2+2z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z^2+2z)^n,
$$
implying, by induction, that each $a_n=0$ for $n>0$ since $(z^2+2z)^n=2^n z^n+ O(z^{n+1})$ as $z\to 0$.

Now, you can apply the identity theorem, since $f$ must be equal to $a_0$ on $B(1,1)$.

Comment: Definitely. (Y) (awkward emoticon added to meet minimum required characters).

Answer (score 0):

A slick solution for those that know a pinch of Algebra:
Let $f(1)=w$.  Being analytic, if $f$ were non-constant then it would map only finitely many of the points in the (compact) closed annulus $\big\{z: \frac{1}{2}\leq \vert z \vert \leq 2\big\}$ to $w$, so it suffices to show that $f$ takes on the value $w$ infinitely many times on the unit circle.  The unit circle is interesting because it contains *many* finite groups and the squaring map acts as a homomorphism.

In particular let $\omega_{2^k}$ be the standard generator for the (multiplicative) group $G_{2^k}$ of $2^k$th roots of unity .  $\phi:G_{2^{k+1}}\longrightarrow G_{2^{k}}$ given by $\phi(\omega_{2^{k+1}})=(\omega_{2^{k+1}})^2=\omega_{2^{k}}$ is a surjective group homomorphism. (Surjectivity isn't strictly needed but this is an easy consequence of $\ker \phi =\big\{\pm 1\big\}$ and the Counting Formula.)

Then $f\big(G_2\big) = f\big(\phi(G_2)\big)= f\big(G_1\big)=\big\{w\big\}$ and in general
$f\big(G_{2^{k+1}}\big) = f\big(\phi(G_{2^{k+1}})\big)= f\big(G_{2^{k}}\big)=\big\{w\big\}$
where the RHS follows by induction hypothesis.  Thus

$\big\{w\big\}=f\big(G_{2^k}\big)$
for $k \in \mathbb N\implies$ $f$ is constant in our domain $\mathbb C-\big\{0\big\}$